# How display image in html while limit access to those?

Tags: php, javascript, html, image

My problem is when you use for exemple :

```
<img src="/img.jpg" />
```

the src has to be an image and the image has to be accessible to the person. I want to be able to control the access to those image (if the user is logged for example). IF the person has not access to the image, he can't access it. My script that controls the access to an image is a php file.

I know .htaccess can limit access to ressources, but I need to valid in the php file. Is there a way to do this or to load the image with javascript (using ajax request) and changing the source of the image to the location of the image in the temp folder?

Comment: You may do it with AJAX and JQuery, or check users status befor printing an img and then on view deside print it or not.

Comment: that's the part I don't know how to do it... tried to use header to send the image and use readfile/imagejped but it doesn't work. Maybe I do it wrong but when you ask the link directly it download the image but when placed in the src attribute... the image don't show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your image source doesn't necessarily have to point to the real image, neither does it have to be an image:

```
<img src="images.php?f=img.jpg" />
```

Then you can write a PHP script which does the required validations and return the image afterwards through the script

```
$image = basename($_GET['f']);
if (user_has_access()) {
    // You have to determine / send the appropriate MIME-type manually
    header('content-type: image/jpg');
    readfile($image);
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
}
```

Comment: gonna try with this... I already tried something like that with readfile/imagejpeg but maybe I was sending a bad header.

Comment: This solution might be extremely costly if file is big readfile() would be better.

Comment: ok it's working... I was doing something wrong. Maybe the extra headers I added were invalidating the resquest. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bartek well thats an easy adjustment ;)

Comment: You can store the binary of the image in say a `BLOB` field in a MySQL DB and fetch that as well.  As with this solution if someone was savvy enough to know the path to `img.jpg` they could bypass the PHP validation, unless you protected it with additional means (such as for example, storing images in a directory only your script has access to).

Answer (score 2):

```
$image = basename($_GET['image']);
if (validation()) {
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    readfile($image);
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
}
```

basename is mandatory, of a hacker will have every password stored on your server.
correct content type
sane memory consumption

Comment: Adding content type recognition will make this solution perfect

Comment: @Bartek it is not needed. The browser will show them all correctly with same header

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="/image.php?id=myImage.jpg">
```

And myImage.jpg:

```
<?php 
$imageName = $_GET['id'];
$ctype="image/jpg";
$extension = substring($imageName, strstr($imageName, '.'));

switch($extension) {
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break; 
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break; 
    case "jpeg": 
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break; 
}
if (someValidation_here) {
    header("Content-Type: $ctype");
    $handle = fopen($imageName, "rb");
    echo fread($handle, filesize($imageName));
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Serve your images with PHP

You can limit access using with PHP, if the PHP is outputting the image contents.

By using the src tag http://www.example.com, you are not using PHP, your web server is serving up the image on its own.

To output an image with PHP, make sure you set your header variable appropriately.

For example:

```
<?php

if($user->isAuthenticated())
{
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg ($server_image_path);

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    imagejpeg($image, NULL, 75);    

    imagedestroy($image);
}
else 
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PHP ... see [imagejpeg](https://www.php.net/imagejpeg) for an example ... you then have the `img` as follows :

```
<img src="/myfile.php" />
```

or use your PHP file to grab an image and output it using :

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
echo file_get_contents("yourimage.jpg");
```

Comment: what do I have to do in the php file. I tried this solution but didn't work.

Comment: @maniak click on the link in my answer to see the example - this shows you how to render your own image

Comment: ok thanks... and is there a genral mime for images or I'll always have to verify the type and send the corresponding mime

Answer (score -1):

You can ceep user_login_status in your $_SESSION, and on a view part check it

```
<?if ($_SESSION['user_status'] == 'login'){?>
  <img src="/img.jpg" />
<?}else{?>
  // some stuff instead of <img/>
<?}?>
```